# How to send reminder by using list item created user?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I need to send mail if created item in list past three from "created" field and "Process status" field is equal to Pending.

[image]

Instead of mention the date i want mention this formula "created <= now-3" but i cant add this workflow designer. Kindly help me this question and give any other method do this.

Comment: Remainder mail should be feature days not for previous days, Created is system field which is updated when you created item. Can you please define you query in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Create one calculated field "Example: Notification Date" and assign the formula `=Today+3` in your list setting.

- I had created similar due date notification email alert send to User
- I think you have to pause your workflow in order to run the notification email

[image: SP Designer Workflow]

Comment: As per your answer i have done condition and mentioned below. But this mail send only one time per day, that condition i dont know. Kindly advice me how to do it.          "If Current Item:notification date is greater than or equal to Today
 Email Current Item:Created By"